# Rails paperclip gem tests failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, model-view-controller

`rake test` puts out this:

```
  1) Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_create_product:
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError: No handler found for "lorem.jpg"
    app/controllers/products_controller.rb:27:in `create'
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:26:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'

  2) Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_update_product:
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError: No handler found for "lorem.jpg"
    app/controllers/products_controller.rb:46:in `block in update'
    app/controllers/products_controller.rb:45:in `update'
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:44:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
```

and the controller looks like so:

```
def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.image = params[:product][:image]
    ....
end
```

and the test controller looks like so: http://pastebin.com/j3fZwJNA

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

use `Rack::Test::UploadedFile` for test file and real fixtures

like this 

`Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new 'spec/fixtures/images/test.png', 'image/png'`